# Main must return a value

Tags: c++

I've been working through the "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++" book, and this example was meant to illustrate how data can be lost in type conversions. But when I tried to execute it, it keeps telling me 'Main' : must return a value. I tried using "return 0;" after the curly brace for the while loop, but then it gave errors around "Unresolved externals".

I've copied the code from the book to Visual Studio and everything else I've copied has worked as expected - would anyone be able to tell me how I could fix this please? I don't know why it's happening with this specific example or how to make it stop asking for a return value.

Sorry if this is dumb, I'm very inexperienced and I've tried googling for an answer, but suggested solutions like "return 0" don't work :)!

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    double d = 0;

    while (cin >> d)
    {

        int i = d;
        char c = i;
        int i2 = c;
        cout << "d==" << d
        << " i==" << i
        << " i2==" << i2
        << " char(" << c << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the whole program.  I'm going to guess that it's the `cout` and that you are neither including `iostream` nor `using namespace std;`.  And you still do need to return something from main.

Comment: What part of this simple 5-word error message don't you understand?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to include that I was using "#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h" which is something given to us to use those!

Comment: @EJP It's easy to be snarky, but C++ doesn't require a return from `main`.

Comment: Are you perhaps building a Win32 application (as opposed to a Console application), which requires `WinMain` instead of `main`? (your specific unresolved external error message would help us determine that)

Comment: You said the error was "Main must return a value". Are you sure it was Main with a capital M? If so, then that's a different Main from the main you've shown us here.

Comment: ...Okay, I used a capital M.

I am so so sorry it took me this long to figure that out. 

This is embarrassing. I knew that capitalisation and the way you type things had to be very precise but...I just kept missing that.

Thank you Klitos (and everyone else!)

*Is really embarrassed*

Comment: @Dean don't be - it's an easy mistake to make, especially for a beginner.

Comment: **−1** because this is **not the real code**.

Answer (score 3):

> I tried using "return 0;" after the curly brace for the while loop, but then it gave errors around "Unresolved externals".

That's a separate, unrelated problem uncovered by fixing the first one. Add the return, then deal with the unresolved externals error.

Comment: Problem is, it shouldn't be an error. `main` does not require a return statement, even though it does require the return type of `int` (it's unique that way).

Comment: While I think this is helpful, it's not really an answer.

Comment: @erip The OP thinks "return 0" doesn't work because another error pops up, and my answer is that it does work and the OP should leave it in. It doesn't answer what an unresolved externals error is, but that's a separate question.

Answer (score -1):

If that's your whole program, you're unresolved external is most likely `iostream`.  You need to include that and use the correct namespace.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Better yet, forgo the `using` statement and use `std::cout` so that you don't have to worry about namespace collision.  See this question [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/691711)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or `using std::cout; using std::cin;`

Comment: Downvote for even mentioning `using namespace std`. The answer is also incorrect, but that comes second.

Comment: @SergeyA I'll be sure to downvote every JavaScript question I see that is missing a `"use strict"` statement from now on.

Comment: @zero298, this is your life and you alone are responsible for choices you make.

Comment: "Unresolved external" is a linker error. A missing header would cause compilation errors and would not fix linking errors.

Comment: @zero298: the header included in the OP's code is something Bjarne cooked up for the book, and as I recall it (in turn) includes `<iostream>`. And yes, I think there's even a, gasp!, `using namespace std;`. Those are not bad decisions for the specific purpose, but Bjarne's use of an unholy macro for something was a disaster there.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, since I believe to be `using namespace std` to be an absolute evil, I consistently downvote questions which suggest typing this incantation to fix the problem. Because OP is going to use those words. And than will develop of habit of doing so - it helped last time! And than... I think you know what's going to happen than.